# issue with .get() in tkinter, python 3.7

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am having an issue with my code where the .get() returns "   " when I enter something into the Tkinter entry box. the purpose of the code is to take the entry and store it in a database using sqlite3. I can't put my code on the internet because it is an assignment that will be put through a plagiarism software however I will put an image of the code that isn't working (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCbXf.jpg) and if you email me at cyrilthomasalex@gmail.com I will send you the full code. I'm new to stack overflow and I know you guys hate it when it's inconvenient to access the code but please help me I've been stuck on this for over 2 hours!!

Comment: Please don't post links to code, and especially not links to _pictures_ of code. Take the time to create a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `textvariable` option for entry widgets. This allows you to have a variable that is automatically updated to the current entry value.

This short example illustrates this system, obviously you would be using your database instead of simply printing the results to the terminal:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class login_win:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.username = tk.StringVar()
        signusername = tk.Entry(self.master, borderwidth=0, textvariable=self.username)
        signusername.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        signpassword = tk.Entry(self.master, borderwidth=0, textvariable=self.password)
        signpassword.grid(row=1, column=0)

        login_butt = tk.Button(self.master, text="Login", command=self.login)
        login_butt.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def login(self):
        print(self.username.get(), self.password.get())


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    login_win(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this helps,

If you want to read more about tkinter and its features I would thoroughly recommend checking out [effbot](https://effbot.org/)

James